# How to Create A Stacked Column Plot of Multiple Variables in R (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

Currently, I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Month   Total Revenue    Dues   Total Retail    Other Revenue
8/31/2020   36615.00     30825  1200            4590
9/30/2020   38096.69     34322  2779.4          995.29
10/31/2020  43594.15     35936  2074.68         5583.47
11/30/2020  51856.9      43432  993.5           7431.4
```

I want to create a plot (which I imagine should be a stacked column) in ggplot that shows the revenue mix by type for each month. For my data, Total Revenue is the sum of dues, total retail and other revenue. Dues, total retail and other revenue should stack on top of each other, each having its own colour. I also want labels on the column chart describing what percentage of the total revenue is from each source of income.

I can plot the total revenue with no issues, but I cannot seem to wrap my head around splitting the columns up. My only successful example so far is as follows.

```
# Create Column Plot of Total Revenue
library(tidyverse)
plot1 <- ggplot(August_Data, aes(Month_End, `Total Revenue`)) + geom_col()
```

This example obviously does not split up the revenue into the correct subcategories. I thought that using the fill command may work however I face an error.

```
plot1 <- ggplot(August_Data, aes(Month_End, `Total Revenue`)) + geom_col(aes(fill = C(Dues, `Total Retail`, `Other Revenue`)))
```

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update after clarification:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
    mutate(Month = mdy(Month)) %>% # this line is not necessary in OPs original code (not the one presented here)
    pivot_longer(
        cols = c("Dues", "TotalRetail", "OtherRevenue"),
        # cols = -c(Month_End, SID) in OPs original code
        names_to = "names", 
        values_to = "values"
    ) %>% 
    mutate(percent = values/TotalRevenue*100) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Month, y= values, fill= names))+
    geom_col() +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(percent,1),"%")), 
              position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 5)
```

[image]

**First answer:**
You were almost there. Pivot longer and add `fill`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
    mutate(Month = mdy(Month)) %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        -Month, 
        names_to = "names", 
        values_to = "values"
    ) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Month, y= values, fill= names))+
    geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: This should work with your dataframe also: `df %>% 
    mutate(Month = mdy(Month)) %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        cols = c("TotalRevenue", "Dues", "TotalRetail", "OtherRevenue"),
        names_to = "names", 
        values_to = "values"
    ) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Month, y= values, fill= names))+
    geom_col()`

Comment: In short: data in long format is what ggplot needs to process. And lubridate is my favorite package to work with dates. :-)

Comment: Hey, this is awesome! However, the columns shouldn't include Total Revenue. Instead, TR is the sum of the other three variables. Therefore the values are doubled. Unfortunately, I am also receiving an error on my side. The full data frame has 66 variables, including a UniqueID identifier for each row. When I run this on my end, I am getting the following error ```Error: Can't combine `Month_End` <datetime<UTC>> and `SID` <character>.``` Any idea for how to proceed? Also, note that the column is actually month_end in the original dataset. Somehow I changed it to month when producing my data.

Comment: Try this: change the line with `cols = ...` to `cols = -c(Month_End, SID)`.

Comment: The fix you gave in the previous comment went through, but it gave a blank plot for its output. When I add ```cols = -c(Month_End, SID)``` I get a compiling error with the original ```Error: Can't combine `Unique ID` <character> and `Month_End` <datetime<UTC>>.``` Thanks for all the help, sorry it seems tricky.

Comment: The full warning before the blank plot is ```Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` column `Month`.
i `Month = mdy(Month_End)`.
i All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
4: In min(diff(sort(x))) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
5: Removed 4305 rows containing missing values (position_stack).  ```

Comment: How does `Month_end` look like: give me the value of one cell and what class is  `Month_end`?

Comment: ```$ Month_End : POSIXct[1:1435], format: "2020-08-31"```

Comment: ok: remove this line `mutate(Month = mdy(Month))` from code

Comment: I did that and removed "Total Revenue" and I got the plot I want. Thank you very much. Any idea how to add a label with the % of Total Revenue that `Dues`, `Other Revenue`, `Total Retail` represent?

Comment: Yes I plan on it but are you able to add text labels representing what percentage of total revenue is through dues, total retail or other revenue? I don't mean to be ungrateful but it was in my original question.

Comment: Calculate the percent `mutate(percent = values/TotalRevenue*100)` and add this line `geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(percent,1),"%")), 
              position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 5)` to ggplot

Comment: When I do that it adds a data label for each point in my data set. Basically, each column is flooded with over 100 labels. I tried grouping by `month_date` but and using the mean `Total Revenue` but that did not work. I'll accept your answer and upvote after this, if It still isn't working I'll open up another question. You've been incredibly helpful thank you

Comment: I cannot upvote because my reputation is only 11, I will upvote once I get the proper credentials. Thanks again for all the help